# How to send multiple objects using nodejs and georedis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have 4 sets in redis DB , I want to get near by locations from all 4 sets and send back as an api result, below codes are working fine when I am using for only 1 set, but my requirement is to get from all 4 sets, please help me.

```
router.route('/get_near_by').post(function(req, res) {

var geo = georedis.initialize(client, {
    zset: 'LocationsSet',
    nativeGeo: false
});
var luxuryXL = geo.addSet('luxuryXL');
var luxurySedan = geo.addSet('luxurySedan');
var sedanFour = geo.addSet('sedanFour');
var sedanSix = geo.addSet('sedanSix');
var lat = req.body.lat;
var lng = req.body.lng;
var result = [];

var options = {
    withCoordinates: true, // Will provide coordinates with locations, default false
    withHashes: true, // Will provide a 52bit Geohash Integer, default false
    withDistances: true, // Will provide distance from query, default false
    order: 'ASC', // or 'DESC' or true (same as 'ASC'), default false
    units: 'km', // or 'km', 'mi', 'ft', default 'm'
    count: 10, // Number of results to return, default undefined
    accurate: true // Useful if in emulated mode and accuracy is important, default false
};

luxuryXL.nearby({latitude: lat, longitude: lng}, 5000, options, function(err, luxuryXL){
    if(err) {
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        return res.send(luxuryXL);
    }
   });
});
```

Below are the codes I tried but they are not working -

```
luxuryXL.nearby({latitude: lat, longitude: lng}, 5000, options, function(err, luxuryXL){
    if(err) {
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        result['a'] = res.send(luxuryXL);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query from 4 sets parallely or sequentially and send them. I suggest use promises like async or bluebird to do parallel querying and join them together and send across response. Hope this helps, let me know if you have any further questions